# Using Relentless Rage after Rage Beyond Death?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, rage

Can a Zealot Barbarian use Rage Beyond Death, kill all the enemies (while at 0 HP) and then use Relentless Rage (or Relentless Endurance) to go back to 1 HP and thus avoid death?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?

Comment: @ObliviousSage Sorry about that! Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Related: "[What happens when you cast Death Ward on a raging level 14 Zealot Barbarian who is at 0 HP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165994)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This does not work

Both Relentless Endurance and Relentless Rage include the following bits:

> [...] If you drop to 0 hit points [...]

> [...] When you are reduced to 0 hit points [...]

These are both features that activate precisely when you hit 0 HP, thus, when you would first fall to 0 HP you can choose to use these features *instead* of dropping to 0 HP. If you choose not to use them, taking damage while at 0 HP does not cause you to then drop back to 0 or be reduced again to 0 and thus does *not* allow you to use these features. These features both only activate when going from a positive number of hit points down to zero and thus cannot activate during Rage Beyond Death.

---

This is similar to the following question:

- [What happens when you cast Death Ward on a raging level 14 Zealot Barbarian who is at 0 HP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165994)

It asks about *death ward* which states, similar to Relentless Rage and Relentless Endurance:

> [...] The first time the target would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, the target instead drops to 1 hit point [...]

The answers there explain that this effect is not triggered by taking damage while already at 0 HP:

> [...] The first trigger only kicks in when the barbarian takes damage that would drop them to 0 hit points for the first time. Since they are already at 0 hit points [...] this trigger does not occur at any point during Rage Beyond Death [...]

> [...] If they're at 0 hp, and they would take damage, they instead gain a failed death saving throw. Death Ward doesn't prevent that; it would only stop damage from reducing the creature to 0 hp. [...]